# 3D Flip Animation... Backface Visibility issues

Tags: css

I am using a CSS3 3D Flip Animation on my website here:

https://8wayrun.com/forums/
(mouse over the 8WAYRUN logo at the top)

In every browser, it looks great... except for Firefox.

I have it's CSS (.less) as follows:

```
        .logo-coin
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            &.flipped { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
        }
```

As you can see, backface-visiblity should be hidden. And it is, in all browsers except Firefox.

In Firefox, the backface-visibility is hidden only on the normal coin. However, on the flipped coin, the backface is showing... even though its clearly respecting the hidden in the unflipped coin.

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to prefix it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility#Browser_compatibility? `-webkit-backface-visibility`. When I tested in FF developer it works fine or at least Chrome and FF looked the same

Comment: I tried that... didn't make a difference.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in FF that can be resolved if you add `transform: translateY(0);` on the parent element. No need for `-webkit-backface-visibility` either.

```
.logo-coin {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(0);
        &.flipped { transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a bizarre fix.